# serverless-api-gateway-caching plugin is not setting the cache size

Tags: serverless-framework

I try to set the AWS API Gateway cache using the serverless-api-gateway-caching plugin.

All is working fine, except the cacheSize.

This is my configuration for the caching:

```
      caching:
        enabled: true
        clusterSize: '13.5'
        ttlInSeconds: 3600
        cacheKeyParameters:
          - name: request.path.param1
          - name: request.querystring.param2
```

The cache is configured correctly, but the **cache size is always the default one '0.5'**

Any idea about what is wrong?

```
sls -v
1.42.3
node --version
v9.11.2
serverless-api-gateway-caching: 1.4.0
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of "Cache Capacity" setting is global per stage, it is not possible to set it per endpoint.

So the plugin is going to check this parameter only in the servelerless global configuration, ignoring it at the endpoint level.

It means that the right configuration is:

```
custom:
  apiGatewayCaching:
    enabled: true
    clusterSize: '13.5'
```